# Sharing resources across unit tests and instrumentation tests in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

Now that Google has added [experimental unit test support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support), how might one go about sharing resources across both unit tests and instrumentation test?

For example, say I have a `TestUtils.java` class that I want accessible in both my unit tests and my instrumentation tests. If I put it in my `src/test/java` folder, it will be accessible to my unit tests. If I put it in my `src/androidTest/java` folder, it will be accessible to my instrumentation tests. How do I make it accessible to both?

The only solution I see right now is putting it in `src/debug/java`, but is there a better way?

Comment: You can always tell Gradle that there is more than one directory of source to pull from. I don't know if there's a cleaner answer, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare good idea! Adding `android.sourceSets.androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java', 'src/test/java']` and vice-versa worked

Comment: This article covers that exact topic: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/

Answer (score 4):

```
android {  
  sourceSets {
    String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
    test {
      java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
    androidTest {
      java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: What's about doing this accross the modules?